# Deploying VSTO Add in created on VS 2017

Tags: vsto, visual-studio-2017

I have created an add in and testing it and it works great.

But how do I now deploy it to our users?

If I run the VSTO file as admin it doesnt install it for the other users.

They each have to run the VSTO file.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways for deploying VSTO based solutions:

- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx)
- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I dont think there is a InstallShield for Visual Studio 2017 though?

Comment: You can create an MSI installer by installing an extension to Visual Studio 2017 - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects . Or just use WiX or any other tool for that.